# I want to implement captcha for my android application. Will using a Jar for the same be helpful? If yes. which is good and how do i use them?

Tags: android, jar, captcha, implementation

I want to implement captcha for my android application login. Will using a Jar be helpful? If yes, which is good and how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is easy to implement the technique of captcha in android or in any other platform by using `Jar`. what you have to do is to put some images into the drawable, put an ImageView right above your EditView and linked those images with an Array or any collection in which you saved the correct text of the images ... then on button click get the ID for the random image and verify it with the saved collection of text.

Various libraries are available to implement CAPTCHA in android. Have a look at :-

- CAPTCHA in Java using reCAPTCHA :-
  (https://github.com/ayltai/Android-Lib-reCAPTCHA)
- Android-Easy-Captcha :- (This is the easiest one I
  found)(https://github.com/floydfix/Android-Easy-Captcha)
- SimpleCaptcha :- (http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/)
- JCaptcha     :- (http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Android-Easy-Captcha is helpful to implement captcha easily